# General theory of graph coloring

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

In Ben Steven's article [Colored graphs and their properties](http://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/SeniorProjectArchive/2008/stevens.pdf) I read:

> We "color" a graph by assigning various colors to the vertices of that
>   graph. [...] this process of coloring is generally governed by a set
>   of **coloring rules**. For example, the most basic set of coloring rules,
>   referred to as regular coloring, consists of a single rule: no two
>   adjacent vertices may have the same color.

What I am looking for is a truly *general* theory of graph colorings and resp. *general* coloring rules.

---

**Edit:** With "general" I mean: considering in a systematic way different "natural" and "important"coloring functions (not all of them at once), studying their properties and relating them in insightful ways.

(Compare this to general graph theory: The general graph is just a function $V\times V \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ and at that level of generality one might doubt that there's much of a theory. But there **is**.)

Comment: Where do the context-free grammars enter into it?

Comment: Via the grammatical roles (= colors) the grammatical constituents (= symbols of the alphabet) do play.

Comment: Any hint for downvoting is welcome.

Comment: It wasn't me. ${}{}$

Comment: Didn't want to blame anyone.

Comment: I don't know if this is remotely close to what you're looking for but I remember this book has some graph logic in it: http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Strange_Logic_of_Random_Graphs.html?id=u2c3LpjWs7EC&redir_esc=y

Comment: A coloring is a function from the vertices of a (finite) graph to an initial segment of the natural numbers. A coloring rule is a subset of the set of all such functions. At that level of generality, I doubt there's much of a theory.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I edited my question to make clearer what I mean with "general theory".